# Is there any testing tool/framework for unit testing of Oracle ADF bounded task flow?

Tags: unit-testing, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

The ADF EMG Task Flow Tester is a web-based testing tool for ADF bounded task flows, but not for automated testing. Is there any other automated tool, so that i can achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

What sort of testing are you looking to undertake? Functional, stress/load?

Looks to Selenium or Oracle Application Test Suite (OATS) for functional.  Look to OATS or Apache JMeter as options for stress/load.

The advantage of OATS over other options is it has intelligence built in to understand the ADF framework.

Comment: Function testing of TaskFlow, I am looking for automated taskflow testing tool.